# What is the character limit of Google Translate's website translation service?

Tags: google-translate

Using Google Translate, I managed to translate a webpage containing approximately 150000 characters, excluding spaces and HTML tags, from Korean to English. However, for a larger webpage, I got an error saying that the page is too big. So the limit is greater than 150000 characters, but my question is, what is the exact character limit for translating webpages?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)